# Repeat a regex per line

Tags: regex

Suppose we have the below text information:

```
FEE AA       XXX093       Some Fee bla bla bla
FEE BB       YYY111       Another Fee bla bla bla
```

I can capture fee code (AA) and fee amount (XXX093) with this regex:

```
FEE (?<feecode>[A-Z]{2}) {7}(?<feeamt>[A-Z]{3}[0-9. ]{1,8}).*\n
```

But this only captures this information for the fee on the first line (AA), how can I modify the regex to grab both (or X number of) fees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `\n` as it prevents from matching the last line in the string (since it ends with no `\n`):

```
FEE (?<feecode>[A-Z]{2}) {7}(?<feeamt>[A-Z]{3}[0-9. ]{1,8}).*
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW3rL2/1).

Alternatively, if can specify the end of string (`$`):

```
FEE (?<feecode>[A-Z]{2}) {7}(?<feeamt>[A-Z]{3}[0-9. ]{1,8}).*(?:\n|$)
```

Here is [a variation of the regex](https://regex101.com/r/yW3rL2/2) with `multiline` option to only match the information on separate lines:

```
^FEE (?<feecode>[A-Z]{2}) {7}(?<feeamt>[A-Z]{3}[0-9. ]{1,8}).*$
```

Comment: BTW, what is the language you are using, C#?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `\n` character at the last and also remove space from the character class. So that the second capturing group won't capture also the spaces which follows the feeamount.

```
FEE (?<feecode>[A-Z]{2}) {7}(?<feeamt>[A-Z]{3}[0-9.]{1,8})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zQ0eJ9/3)

Comment: add start of the line anchor  `^` before `FEE` if necessary.